# Render Embedded Image in Email Body using Microsoft Graph or Outlook REST API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

When we get email using Microsoft Graph/Outlook REST API it's body contains the references for embedded images like below.

```
<img src="cid:image001.jpg@1D3E60C.5A00BC30">
```

I am looking to find out a way so i can display the embedded images properly as the above image tag does not display any image. I have done some search but did not found any help on that.

Below is sample code for getting an email by id using Microsoft Graph API.

```
// Get the message.
Message message = await graphClient.Me.Messages[id].Request(requestOptions).WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount()).GetAsync();
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I sure did, I should do a blog post on it. Long story short, you have to loop through your messages, find the ones that have attachments, make a second call to get the image binary (bite array) and replace that "cid" value to that binary.

Comment: @redhedjim I have posted one of possible solution. You may check it if you have not solved this yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For getting attached resources with email using Microsoft Graph API you need to get email like below.

```
// Get the message with all attachments(Embedded or separately attached).
Message message = await graphClient.Me.Messages[id].Request(requestOptions).WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount()).Expand("attachments").GetAsync();
```

Once you have all attachments with email detail you need to iterate through attachments list and check if attachment IsInline property is set as true then simply replace the

> cid:image001.jpg@1D3E60C.5A00BC30

with Base64String created from bytes array of attachment.

```
string emailBody = message.Body.Content;
foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
{
   if (attachment.IsInline.HasValue && attachment.IsInline.Value)
   {
     if ((attachment is FileAttachment) &&(attachment.ContentType.Contains("image")))
     {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
        byte[] contentBytes = fileAttachment.ContentBytes;
        string imageContentIDToReplace = "cid:" + fileAttachment.ContentId;
        emailBody = emailBody.Replace(imageContentIDToReplace, 
        String.Format("data:image;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(contentBytes as 
        byte[])));
     }

  }
}
```

Now render the email body using emailBody variable it will display all embedded images.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to display logo image on image tag using graph Api in C#.

```
var fileAttachment = new FileAttachment
            {
                ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                Name = Path.GetFileName(attachment),
                ContentLocation = attachment,
                ContentBytes = contentBytes,
                ContentType = contentType,
                ContentId= contentId,
                IsInline = true
            };
```

Note : Here **IsInline = true** must need to be added if you want to display image on image tag only not as attachment.